# xamarin three-choice button color

Tags: xamarin

I am using the Three-choice Button component in xamarin, but I don't know of a way to change the button color. The font and shadow ect can be changed, but I would like to change the grey color.

Can anyone provide some insight on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this a different way. I am using a normal ios switch, and just changing the background colour of the switch, ie Green, Grey or Orange.
Not exactly the answer to my question, but looks neater than the component did.